# Boost compile error cstddef: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, boost

When I want to use boost, I meet compile error, also can not find `cstddef` in `/usr/include/boost`:

```
In file included from server.c:10:0:
/usr/include/boost/config/select_stdlib_config.hpp:17:19: fatal error: cstddef: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

In Ubuntu 12.

Comment: Since `<cstddef>` is a header that should be distributed with your C++ compiler, it is not surprising that Boost does not provide it. Do you have an operational C++ compiler (which supports at least the C++98 standard)?  If not, you'll need to install or upgrade to a compiler that does. Check the prerequisites at Boost, too.

Comment: are you using gcc or g++ to compile your .c file?